# Angular DataTables : Multiple datatables individual column filters are not working

Tags: angular, datatables, filtering, multiple-tables

Angular DataTables with Angular way, Multiple data tables filters are not working.

I have two tables, and different API's data. Im trying to implement individual column filters. Any suggestion pls...

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
this.dtTrigger.next();
this.dtElements.forEach((dtElement: DataTableDirective, index: number) => {
  dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
    dtInstance.columns().every(function () {
      const that = this;
      $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
        console.log('search(): ' + that.search());
        console.log('value: ' + (<HTMLInputElement>this)['value']);
        if (that.search() !== (<HTMLInputElement>this)['value']) {
          that.search((<HTMLInputElement>this)['value']).draw();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

}
2 Tables are not connected. They have 2 different sql tables. I load with 2 different WEB API. –

```
ngOnInit(): void {
const that = this;
this.dtOptions[0] = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  lengthChange: false,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback: any) => {
    dataTablesParameters.searchCriteria = this.searchCriteria;
    that.httpClient
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'http://localhost:1421/api/Bureau/',
        dataTablesParameters,
        {}
      )
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        this.bureaux = resp.Bureaux;
        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: [],
        });
      });
  }
};

this.dtOptions[1] = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 10,
  lengthChange: false,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback: any) => {
    dataTablesParameters.searchCriteria = this.searchCriteria;
    that.httpClient
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'http://localhost:1421/api/Centrevote/',
        dataTablesParameters,
        {}
      )
      .subscribe((resp) => {
        this.centrevotes = resp.Centrevote;
        console.log('centre: ' + this.centrevotes);

        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: [],
        });
      });
  },
};
```

}

Comment: what is not working now ?

Comment: individual column filters for two tables not working

Comment: For two tables? How you manage to load data to tables? Two are connected or not ?

Comment: 2 Tables are not connected. They have 2 different sql tables. I load with 2 different WEB API.

Comment: You're not using Angular else JQuery, Why? BTW, What is DataTableDirective? What library are you using?

Comment: I am using Angular (ngoninit,ngAfterViewInit). I am using Angular DataTables Library